# Como contar el numero de filas de una datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables

Necesito contar el numero de filas de una datatable y que cuanto este supere las 11 porque cuentan la cabecera me saque una alerta diciendo cuantas filas hay

```js
var table = $('#tblDistribucionZonas').DataTable({
  dom: 'lBfrtip',
  pageLength: 10,
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
  ],
  language: {
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primero",
      "last": "Ultimo",
      "next": "Siguiente",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para contar la cantidad de filas podes usar la función **[count()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/count())**, es recomendable leer la documentación de [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) ya que es muy completa y dudas como estas se resuelven prácticamente solas.

Te dejo un ejemplo (*oculto porque es bastante larga la creación de la tabla*)

```js
var table = $('table').DataTable(
{
  pageLength: 10,
  //Resto de la configuración
});

//Listener para el boton..
$('button').on('click',function()
{  
    //Muestro la cantidad de filas
    console.log("Filas: " + table.rows().count());
    
    //Muestro la cantidad de columnas
    console.log("Columnas: " + table.columns().count());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Columna 1</th>
      <th>Columna 2</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Ejemplo de dato 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo de dato 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ejemplo de dato 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo de dato 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ejemplo de dato 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo de dato 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ejemplo de dato 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo de dato 2</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<button> Contar Filas </button>
```

Como se ve en el ejemplo anterior `count()` devuelve un `integer` por lo que ya podes aplicar la lógica y validar que sea menor o igual a `11` y prevenir el agregado de más filas, o lo que necesites hacer con este dato